# How can I validate a unique field when I edit an object with sequelize

Tags: validation, sequelize.js

I use the following code to validate the uniqueness of the user's pseudo when I create the user object. The problem is that when I edit a user object I need to retrieve the current user.id. How can I do that?

```
pseudo:   {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(150), 
  allowNull: false, 
  validate: {
    len: {args: [3, 150], msg: "Pseudo shall contains at least 3 characters"},
    isUnique: function(value, next) {
      User.find({
          where: {pseudo: value},
          attributes: ['id']
      }).done(function(error, user) {
        if (error)
            return next(error);

        if (user)
            return next('Pseudo already in use!');

        next();
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
pseudo:   {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(150), 
  allowNull: false, 
  validate: {
    len: {args: [3, 150], msg: "Pseudo shall contains at least 3 characters"},
    isUnique: function(value, next) {
      var id = this.getDataValue('id');

      User.find({
          where: {pseudo: value},
          attributes: ['id']
      }).done(function(error, user) {
        if (error)
            return next(error);

        if (user && user.id !== id)
            return next('Pseudo already in use!');

        next();
      });
    }
  }
},
```